# Python ingestion of csv files

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, automation

I am trying to ingest daily csv data into Python. I have different files such as follows for each day.I need help in appending two columns where the values from the columns are from the file name, for eg first column should take the value before '_' and the second column takes the date part from the file name.

```
  board_2019-08-08.csv
  sign_2019-08-08.csv
  Summary_2019-08-08.csv
```

Code :

```
path = "C:\xyz\Files\ETL\Dashboard"
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

for file in all_files: 
    file_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))[0]
    dfn = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = 17)
    dfn['Page'] = 'Dashboard'
    del dfn['Dimension']
    dfn = dfn.iloc[1:]
    dfn.columns = ['LoanId', 'Impressions', 'Page']
```

`

Comment: you want to add new two columns to same file,ex add `board`,`2019-08-08` columns to board_2019-08-08.csv file ?

Comment: That’s correct! For sign_2019-08-08, the two columns would be sign and 2019-08-08 and so on for all the files. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
path = "C:\xyz\Files\ETL\Dashboard"

files = list(filter(lambda x: '.csv' in x, os.listdir('path')))

for file in files:
    pre,post = file.split("_")
    post = post.split(".")[0] 

    dfn = pd.read_csv(f"{path}/{file}", skiprows = 17)

    # assume your inital values for column 0 and 1 is 1

    dfn.insert(0,"column1",value=pre)
    dfn.insert(1,"column2",value=post)

    // rest of your code
```

Comment: Thank for the solution but the values aren’t changing when the file name changes. Any idea?

Comment: I think we are missing something out, the columns are not getting appended according to the find name. It’s appending the same value to every file. For Eg, there are different dates after delimiter but it is assigning just the initial one!

Comment: as a example,in board_2019-08-08.csv file , you need `board`,`2019-08-08` as column values or column names?

Comment: Both!! Thank you fir being so responsive, I tried modifying the insert statement by adding pre and post instead of 1 and 1.

Comment: Rajith, any thoughts on why the loop is not reading all the different files in the folder? Also, for similar file names, its appending the same date from first file to rest of the files.